# First time ask for some permission if don't allow then exit app

Tags: flutter, dart

*In* **flutter** *is there any package or something where I can use this feature when user first time open my app it will ask for permission( like location, file, camera)if user doesn't allow them all app will close?*   Any package/library to achieve like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin for permission
https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler/install

Plus you can store a bool value in your shared preference to know if the user has performed this step.

As per you problem:-
Step 1:- Ask permisssion
Step 2:- Check permission status
Step 3:- Store bool value in you shared preference to check if it is user's first time
Step 4:- If permission status is success, take user to the home screen or dashboard. If permission status is failure, exit the app